# Check if user location is visible on map iphone

Tags: iphone, mapkit, userlocation

I want to hide or show a UIButton weather user's  current location is visible on map.  While testing the code xcode I can see meassage `"User location view is NOT visible but should be. Showing...."` on console in "didUpdateLocation" method if users location is not visible on map.  How can I use this message to generate events in my case to hide or show a UIButton?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to know whether the user location is contained in the currently displayed map region, you can check the `userLocationVisible` property in the `regionDidChangeAnimated` delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    someButton.hidden = !mapView.userLocationVisible;
}
```

If you just want to know whether the user location currently has a value (whether it's visible or not and whether showsUserLocation is on or not), then:

```
if (mapView.userLocation.location == nil)
    NSLog(@"user location not obtained yet");
else
    NSLog(@"user location available (may or may not be currently visible)"):
```

Answer (score 4):

There is property called userLocationVisible.

In Apple Docs

> A Boolean value indicating whether the device’s current location is
>   visible in the map view. (read-only)

Answer (score 1):

if user location is not visible you does not get current lat,long . put the condition if lat ,long == 0. then button hide or show. 
it work on only device(gps)