# MkmapView UsersLocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I am Developing an App which is based on `MKMapView`, and the requirement of the App is to detect whether the userLocation (represented by Blue dot) is lying on the visible area of the screen or it is outside the visible Screen Area.

In the beginning when map gets loaded, it automatically set it's position to the user's location but I want to detect wether current location is in the visible area of screen or not, after user scroll the map view.

Please provide useful solutions and help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if user location is visible on map iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320101/check-if-user-location-is-visible-on-map-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

just use `userLocationVisible` ( I didnt remember but @Volker reminded me)

---

any annotation:

get the location and check if the pixel coordinate is visible

1. get the userLocation from the map
2. get its coordinate
3. convert it to a mappoint (MKMapPointForCoordinate)
4. get the mapview's visible mapRect
5. use MKMapRectContainsPoint

   ```
   MKMapRect visibleRect = self.mapView.visibleMapRect;
   MKMapPoint pt = MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.mapview.userLocation.coordinate);

   BOOL visible = MKMapRectContainsPoint(visibleRect, pt);
   ```

Comment: why not just use `userLocationVisible` ?

Comment: @Volker  :D because I didnt remember that

Comment: and here is the answer to my own question:     - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (!mapView.userLocationVisible) 
        NSLog(@"userlocation is not visible");
    else
        NSLog(@"user location is visible now");
    
}

Comment: and Thankyou Volker and Daij-Djan for you answer, that helped me a exactly what i want to achieve.